Dynamically embed an artboard to multiple other assets in project
Is there a method or a way to create a photoshop canvas with one or multiple artboards, and be able to dynamically add this artboard (like an embedded asset) that will change dynamically in all my other assets when it’s updated.
For example I have a logo in an artboard with a black background. As soon as I have changed the logo or background within the artboard, the other photoshop files (other assets) are updated dynamically. Similar to when you create a color matte and change it, it changes it for everything.

I believe you are looking for linked smart objects
